# Is a function countably additive on a semiring if it assigns zero to the empty set, is finitely additive and countably monotone on the semiring?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, measure-theory

I have learnt using Rana's book:"an introduction to measure and integration"  that on an algebra, finite additivity and countable subadditivity implies countable additivity (if the set function assigns zero to the empty set). But my question is what happens if I have a semialgebra or a semiring??

I think that as I don't know if the finite union of sets belong to the semiring, it is not possible to use finite additivity to prove the another inequality that is necessary for countable additivity. If you can find a counter example, it would be great!!!

Thanks in advance.